# Why am I getting this error message? "Uncaught Initmap is not a function"

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, codepen

I'm using a google map api on codepen. The error is saying:
Ob {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Ob (my api key is written here)}

I'm not sure if I have the wrong CDN, or if codepen is just not optimized to use google maps apis. The map shows up sometimes, and when I refresh the page it disappears. Then it appears again randomly. When it appears it appears great. It just doesn't always appear. I've got a `div id="map></div>` and have made its height 100% as the google maps API suggests.

I'm convinced with the console errors that this must be a problem with the way I've written the JS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a link to the [pen](https://codepen.io/miagenovese/pen/LBgaNp?editors=1010)

And here's my Javascript:

```
function initMap() {

    var frogner = {
        info: '<strong>Lucky Cup Frogner</strong><br>\
                    Bygdøy allé 17<br> 0267 Oslo<br>\
                    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bygd%C3%B8y+all%C3%A9+17,+0262+Oslo/@5 9.9139519,10.728967,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x46416dd3446793cd:0x7273c747063 39df0!8m2!3d59.9160077!4d10.7133661?shorturl=1">Get Directions</a>',
        lat: 59.916010,
        long: 10.713385
    };
  var majorstuen = {
    info: '<strong>Lucky Cup Majorstuen</strong><br>\
                    Neuberggata 20<br> 0367 Oslo<br>\
                    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Neuberggata+20,+0367+Oslo/@59.9275959, 10.7143379,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x46416dda68bbe857:0x45907dac0cbd fae9!8m2!3d59.9275932!4d10.7165266?shorturl=1">Get Directions</a>',
        lat: 59.927557,
        long: 10.716551
  };
  var vika = {
    info: '<strong>Lucky Cup Vika</strong><br>\
                    Haakon VIIs gate 5<br> 0161 Oslo<br>\
                    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Haakon+VIIs+gate+5,+0161+Oslo/@59.9139 519,10.728967,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x46416e7e1b3dfd45:0xc77d49113 796fa12!8m2!3d59.9139492!4d10.7311557?shorturl=1">Get Directions</a>',
        lat: 59.913833,
        long: 10.731125
  };

  var locations = [
    [frogner.info, frogner.lat, frogner.long, 0],
    [majorstuen.info, majorstuen.lat, majorstuen.long, 1],
    [vika.info, vika.lat, vika.long, 2],
  ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.921453, 10.718126),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            };
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work fine when you remove `defer` off your maps script.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I just gave it a try :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `initMap` is used as a callback. Sometimes, it appears that Google maps API calls it back before your script is run and the function properly defined.

You won't have the problem outside of CodePen if you set up the loading sequence wisely.

To synchronize easily in CodePen, here is what I'd do:

Dynamically load the Google Maps script once the function is loaded.

To do that, remove the `<script>` tag at the end of your HTML and add at the end of your JS the following:

```
const googleMapsScript = document.createElement('script');
googleMapsScript.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBorrLWWOEKylh4WCCBuNc4QF9QjX_n0Bw&callback=initMap';
document.head.appendChild(googleMapsScript);
```

It should work 100% of the time this way.

Comment: Ok, it also says right after "You can use the URL of any other Pen and it will include the JavaScript from that Pen." Do you think a solution might be to create a new pen and just put the javascript in there, then include it as a url?

Comment: Please check my edit ;) Basing code from a pen to another could be quite... volatile from my opinion, I never use CodePen or JSFiddle outside of quick demos or sharing troubleshoot. I'd advise you to simply synchronize the loading of Google Maps Script manually inside your JS panel ;)

Comment: I'd like to add that you left your API key in that snippet.